# Gradient of ${\bf z} \mapsto- \frac12 \operatorname{tr} \left( {\bf A} \left( {\bf Y} - {\bf x} {\bf z}^\top \right) {\bf B} ( \cdot )^\top \right)$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, trace, scalar-fields

Given $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrix $\bf A$ and $5 \times 5 $ symmetric matrix $\bf B$, let the scalar field $f : \Bbb R^5 \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$ f ({\bf z}) :=  - \frac12 \operatorname{tr} \left( {\bf A} \left( {\bf Y} - {\bf x} {\bf z}^\top \right) {\bf B} \left( {\bf Y} - {\bf x} {\bf z}^\top \right)^\top \right) $$

where $\operatorname{tr}$ is trace operator, ${\bf x} = {\bf 1}_3$ and $\bf Y$ is a $3 \times 5$ matrix.

I can find $\nabla_{\bf z} f$ by expanding operations inside the trace and following the derivative of trace rules outlined in [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). However, those rules are based on the matrices. Since in my case I am taking a derivative with respect to a vector $\bf z$, would it be reasonable to use those rules? If not,  how can I find $\nabla_{\bf z} f$ in this setting?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: Maybe you can state what you found and we can tell you if it is correct ?

Comment: I think it is reasonable to think $z$ as an $n \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: @obareey But then you can't get rid of the trace

Comment: @Steph What I found is $ x^{T} A(Y- x z^{T})B$. However, I assumed x and z are matrices to get this result.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Could you please elaborate on what you suggested and show me how to proceed with this?

Comment: It is correct. I think it is better (in my opinion) to express the gradient with the same dimension as the vector you are differentiating so I would suggest the transpose of your result.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [cyclic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property) of the trace,

$$ f ({\bf z}) :=  - \frac12 \operatorname{tr} \left( {\bf A} \left( {\bf Y} - {\bf x} {\bf z}^\top \right) {\bf B} \left( {\bf Y} - {\bf x} {\bf z}^\top \right)^\top \right) = \cdots =  - \frac12 \left( \left( {\bf x}^\top {\bf A} \, {\bf x} \right) \left( {\bf z}^\top {\bf B} \, {\bf z} \right) - 2 \left\langle {\bf B} \, {\bf Y}^\top {\bf A} \, {\bf x} , {\bf z} \right\rangle + \operatorname{tr} \left( {\bf A} {\bf Y} {\bf B} {\bf Y}^\top \right) \right) $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks this is much better. I get the following:
$$ \nabla_{z}f = -\frac{1 }{2 } \left( 2(\mathbf{x}^{T} A \mathbf{x} ) B \mathbf{z}    - 2^{T} \right )$$

If my above derivation is correct, then what I found previously by assuming $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{z}$ as matrices is not correct?

Comment: @parx That gradient is correct